# What is logical name in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am new to hibernate and having difficulty in understanding what is the use of logical name in hibernate ?  I have read this http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#PhysicalNamingStrategy

and it says:

> singular NamingStrategy contract actually combined the separate concerns that are now modeled individually as ImplicitNamingStrategy and PhysicalNamingStrategy.

I don't understand what are the 2 concerns talked about here ?
From what I understand, we have a scheme like this:
Java entity class attributes  -> logical name  -> physical name.
Why do we need logical name ?
It says there are 2 stages, why do we need 2 stages ?

Comment: as i understand it, the first stage is to create an implicit name if there is no name specified. from there starts stage 2, where the name will be cast into a physical name. in this stage you can carry out some naming conventions from eg. your company. if you have no need to carry out such conventions, the names will simply stay the same

Comment: @XtremeBaumer But why do we need an implicit name (i.e the first stage)?

Comment: [this doc section explains it pretty good i think](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#naming). carefully read the paragraphs directly below `2.2.1. ImplicitNamingStrategy` and `2.2.2. PhysicalNamingStrategy`. Can't explain better than this i think

Comment: `2.2 Naming strategies` `Part of the mapping of an object model to the relational database is mapping names from the object model to the corresponding database names. Hibernate looks at this as 2 stage process:The first stage is determining a proper logical name from the domain model mapping. A logical name can be either explicitly specified by the user (using @Column or @Table e.g.) or it can be implicitly determined by Hibernate through an ImplicitNamingStrategy contract.
Second is the resolving of this logical name to a physical name which is defined by the PhysicalNamingStrategy contract`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer you are quoting from the same link that I have mentioned in my question.  I find it hard to understand from there and thus asked the question.

Comment: `When an entity does not explicitly name the database table that it maps to, we need to implicitly determine that table name. Or when a particular attribute does not explicitly name the database column that it maps to, we need to implicitly determine that column name. There are examples of the role of the org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategy contract to determine a logical name when the mapping did not provide an explicit name` can't explain it better than this